# Using boto3 through SAM local to interact with Localstack S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, localstack

I am having a strange issue trying to get `boto3` in `AWS SAM local` to connect to `localstack S3`. I know this is especially strange because `SQS` works fine. Both `localstack` and `AWS SAM local` are being invoked to run within a Docker network I've created, called `test`.

My (non-working S3) Python code is:

```
  ACCESS_KEY='123'
  SECRET_KEY='abc'
  s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                      endpoint_url="http://docker.for.mac.localhost:4572",
                      use_ssl=False,
                      aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
  print s3.list_buckets()
```

The above code gives me the error: `An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The specified bucket does not exist: NoSuchBucket`.

However, if I change the code to use `localstack SQS`, like so:

```
  ACCESS_KEY='123'
  SECRET_KEY='abc'
  sqs = boto3.client('sqs',
                      endpoint_url="http://docker.for.mac.localhost:4576",
                      use_ssl=False,
                      aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
  print sqs.list_queues()
```

Everything works fine and it lists me the queues I've created in `localstack SQS`.

Comment: You shouldn't define AWS keys explicitly in your application. Just create AWS profile using `aws configure --profile localstack` and then `export AWS_PROFILE=localstack` in your working environment.

Answer (score 0):

By default the main entry point for all API invocations is (the `EDGE_PORT`) 4566. I am interacting with S3 inside the `localstack/localstack:latest` container over that same port.

In order for it to work I also had to change the AWS SDK config to use `s3ForcePathStyle: true`.

Does the above work for you?